Wrong datas when altering xstep and ystep in tkz-fct
I'd like to plot a graph and some points with tkz-fct in the [0,1.4]×[0,6] rectangle. I beginned with \tkzInit[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=1.4,ymax=6,xscale=0.1,yscale=0.5 command. So the plots are shown right. I then added the \tkzFct[domain=0:1.4,id=pendulum]{3.2294 * x+0,0547} command, and it is plotted absolutely bad.
the code is
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7071]
\tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=1.4,ymin=0,ymax=6,xstep=0.1,ystep=0.5]
\tkzGrid[color=lightgray]
\tkzDrawX[label=$r$ (m),below right=1em]
\tkzLabelX
\tkzDrawY[label={$T^2$ (s$^2$)}]
\tkzLabelY
\tkzDefPoints{%
0.3500  /1.4090 /r1,%
0.6380  /2.6179 /r2,%
0.7560  /3.0625 /r3,%
0.8000  /3.0380 /r4,%
1.0500  /4.2932 /r5,%
1.3300  /5.2212 /r6%
}{
\tkzDrawPoints(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6)
\tkzFct[domain=0:1.4,id=pendulum]{3.9224 * x+0.0547}
\tkzText(1,4){
\pbox
$T^2=3,9224r+0,0547$\\
$R^2=0,9947$
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The table is:

# Curve 0 of 1, 200 points
# Curve title: "((3.9224 * x+0.0547)-0)/0.5"
# x y type
0.00000 0.10940  i
0.07035 0.66130  i
0.14070 1.21319  i
0.21106 1.76509  i
0.28141 2.31698  i
0.35176 2.86888  i
0.42211 3.42077  i
0.49246 3.97267  i
0.56281 4.52456  i
0.63317 5.07646  i
0.70352 5.62835  i
0.77387 6.18025  i
0.84422 6.73215  i
0.91457 7.28404  i
0.98492 7.83594  i
1.05528 8.38783  i
1.12563 8.93973  i
1.19598 9.49162  i
1.26633 10.04352  i
1.33668 10.59541  i
1.40704 11.14731  i
1.47739 11.69921  i
1.54774 12.25110  i
1.61809 12.80300  i
1.68844 13.35489  i
1.75879 13.90679  i
1.82915 14.45868  i
1.89950 15.01058  i
1.96985 15.56247  i
2.04020 16.11437  i
2.11055 16.66626  i
2.18090 17.21816  i
2.25126 17.77006  i
2.32161 18.32195  i
2.39196 18.87385  i
2.46231 19.42574  i
2.53266 19.97764  i
2.60302 20.52953  i
2.67337 21.08143  i
2.74372 21.63332  i
2.81407 22.18522  i
2.88442 22.73711  i
2.95477 23.28901  i
3.02513 23.84091  i
3.09548 24.39280  i
3.16583 24.94470  i
3.23618 25.49659  i
3.30653 26.04849  i
3.37688 26.60038  i
3.44724 27.15228  i
3.51759 27.70417  i
3.58794 28.25607  i
3.65829 28.80796  i
3.72864 29.35986  i
3.79899 29.91176  i
3.86935 30.46365  i
3.93970 31.01555  i
4.01005 31.56744  i
4.08040 32.11934  i
4.15075 32.67123  i
4.22111 33.22313  i
4.29146 33.77502  i
4.36181 34.32692  i
4.43216 34.87882  i
4.50251 35.43071  i
4.57286 35.98261  i
4.64322 36.53450  i
4.71357 37.08640  i
4.78392 37.63829  i
4.85427 38.19019  i
4.92462 38.74208  i
4.99497 39.29398  i
5.06533 39.84587  i
5.13568 40.39777  i
5.20603 40.94967  i
5.27638 41.50156  i
5.34673 42.05346  i
5.41709 42.60535  i
5.48744 43.15725  i
5.55779 43.70914  i
5.62814 44.26104  i
5.69849 44.81293  i
5.76884 45.36483  i
5.83920 45.91672  i
5.90955 46.46862  i
5.97990 47.02052  i
6.05025 47.57241  i
6.12060 48.12431  i
6.19095 48.67620  i
6.26131 49.22810  i
6.33166 49.77999  i
6.40201 50.33189  i
6.47236 50.88378  i
6.54271 51.43568  i
6.61307 51.98757  i
6.68342 52.53947  i
6.75377 53.09137  i
6.82412 53.64326  i
6.89447 54.19516  i
6.96482 54.74705  i
7.03518 55.29895  i
7.10553 55.85084  i
7.17588 56.40274  i
7.24623 56.95463  i
7.31658 57.50653  i
7.38693 58.05843  i
7.45729 58.61032  i
7.52764 59.16222  i
7.59799 59.71411  i
7.66834 60.26601  i
7.73869 60.81790  i
7.80905 61.36980  i
7.87940 61.92169  i
7.94975 62.47359  i
8.02010 63.02548  i
8.09045 63.57738  i
8.16080 64.12928  i
8.23116 64.68117  i
8.30151 65.23307  i
8.37186 65.78496  i
8.44221 66.33686  i
8.51256 66.88875  i
8.58291 67.44065  i
8.65327 67.99254  i
8.72362 68.54444  i
8.79397 69.09633  i
8.86432 69.64823  i
8.93467 70.20013  i
9.00503 70.75202  i
9.07538 71.30392  i
9.14573 71.85581  i
9.21608 72.40771  i
9.28643 72.95960  i
9.35678 73.51150  i
9.42714 74.06339  i
9.49749 74.61529  i
9.56784 75.16718  i
9.63819 75.71908  i
9.70854 76.27098  i
9.77889 76.82287  i
9.84925 77.37477  i
9.91960 77.92666  i
9.98995 78.47856  i
10.06030 79.03045  i
10.13065 79.58235  i
10.20101 80.13424  i
10.27136 80.68614  i
10.34171 81.23804  i
10.41206 81.78993  i
10.48241 82.34183  i
10.55276 82.89372  i
10.62312 83.44562  i
10.69347 83.99751  i
10.76382 84.54941  i
10.83417 85.10130  i
10.90452 85.65320  i
10.97487 86.20509  i
11.04523 86.75699  i
11.11558 87.30889  i
11.18593 87.86078  i
11.25628 88.41268  i
11.32663 88.96457  i
11.39698 89.51647  i
11.46734 90.06836  i
11.53769 90.62026  i
11.60804 91.17215  i
11.67839 91.72405  i
11.74874 92.27594  i
11.81910 92.82784  i
11.88945 93.37974  i
11.95980 93.93163  i
12.03015 94.48353  i
12.10050 95.03542  i
12.17085 95.58732  i
12.24121 96.13921  i
12.31156 96.69111  i
12.38191 97.24300  i
12.45226 97.79490  i
12.52261 98.34679  i
12.59296 98.89869  i
12.66332 99.45059  i
12.73367 100.00248  i
12.80402 100.55438  i
12.87437 101.10627  i
12.94472 101.65817  i
13.01508 102.21006  i
13.08543 102.76196  i
13.15578 103.31385  i
13.22613 103.86575  i
13.29648 104.41765  i
13.36683 104.96954  i
13.43719 105.52144  i
13.50754 106.07333  i
13.57789 106.62523  i
13.64824 107.17712  i
13.71859 107.72902  i
13.78894 108.28091  i
13.85930 108.83281  i
13.92965 109.38470  i
14.00000 109.93660  i

The line must be close to the points because it is a regression line, but it is far away from them. I don't know where the 0.5 factor in the table is come from, and why is the domain 0:14...


Please end our guessing by adding the few missing code lines which make your code snippet compile. Thank you

In the documentation p.11

Lorsque xstep est différent de 1, il est nécessaire de remplacer 
par \x.

Remark: in this case samples=2 is sufficient.
We then have in the .table file
# Curve 0 of 1, 2 points
# Curve title: "((3.9224 * (x*0.1)+0.0547)-0)/0.5"
# x y type
0.00000 0.10940  i
14.00000 11.09212  i

We can see x*0.1 and "y"/0.5, this is the change of units given to gnuplot (choice made with \tkzinit[xstep=0.1,ystep=0.5]
\tkz Fct[domain=0:1.4,samples=2,id=pendulum]{3.9224 * \x+0.0547} gives the same result as \draw(0,0)--(\fpeval{1.4/0.1},\ fpeval{(3.9224*1.4+0.0547)/0.5});
EDIT not (0,0) but  (0,\fpeval{0.0547/0.5})
code
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}



% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=1.4,ymin=0,ymax=6,xstep=0.1,ystep=0.5]
    \tkzGrid[color=lightgray]
    \tkzDrawX[label=$r$ (m),below right=1em]
    \tkzLabelX
    \tkzDrawY[label={$T^2$ (s$^2$)}]
    \tkzLabelY
    \tkzDefPoints{%
    0.3500  /1.4090 /r1,%
    0.6380  /2.6179 /r2,%
    0.7560  /3.0625 /r3,%
    0.8000  /3.0380 /r4,%
    1.0500  /4.2932 /r5,%
    1.3300  /5.2212 /r6%
    }
    % {
    \tkzDrawPoints(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6)
    \tkzFct[domain=0:1.4,samples=2,id=pendulum]{3.9224 * \x+0.0547}
    % \draw(0,\fpeval{0.0547/0.5})--(\fpeval{1.4/0.1},\fpeval{(3.9224*1.4+0.0547)/0.5});
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % \tkzText(1,4){
    % \pbox
    % $T^2=3,9224r+0,0547$\\
    % $R^2=0,9947$
    % }
    %}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Oh, that's my extremely poor french again...
